# Bad File descriptor with multiple pipes

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, pipe

I have the following assignement where I have to reproduce shell pipes with n commands like so :

./pipex infile cmd1 cmd2 cmd3 cmdn ... outfile will reproduce this shell commands :

< infile cmd1 cmd2 cmd3 cmdn... > outfile where outfile and infile represent files.

My programs works as intented but error occurs when I enter a bad command (command that does not exist in shell like "cadt" instead of "cat", more precisely I get the correct output message from my handle error function, but I also get another error from pipe (I think) that is telling me "Bad File descriptor". From that I asssume that I try to read from a pipe that is already close or something like this.
Here is my code

First this is the main function, where all pipes occurs for that I pass my structure t_data as argument where there is all my stored command, I also pass my pipes array.

The logic for that function is that I loop over all my command and I first init my pipes,
then I fork the process, and start my command in the child process then, I close the previous pipes opened, and this goes as long as I have I command in my commands array and at the end I close the previous fd and wait for all process to finish with the wait loop.

```
void    piping(t_data   *data, int pipes[2])
{
    int     i;
    t_cmd   **cmds;
    int     pid_ret;

    cmds = data -> cmd_data;
    i = -1;
    while (cmds[++i])
    {
        if (pipe(pipes) < 0)
            print_err_and_exit("pipex", data, 1);
        data -> init_pipes = 1;
        pid_ret = fork();
        if (pid_ret < 0)
            print_err_and_exit("pipex", data, 1);
        if (pid_ret == 0)
            forking(data, pipes, i);
        if (data -> prev_pipes != -1)
            close_fd(data, data -> prev_pipes, "pipex");
        data -> prev_pipes = pipes[0];
        close_fd(data, data -> pipes[1], "pipex");
    }
    close_fd(data, data -> prev_pipes, "pipex");
    while (wait(NULL) > 0)
        ;
}
```

Here is the forking function, if i == 0 it means that is the first command and that I have to take input from the infile that's why there is a condition on it as well for if i == data -> num_cnds - 1 where I have to redirect the output in the outfile and not STOUT.
if "i" do not met the two first conditions it means that the command is in-between so we take input from previous pipes and close the previous pipes fd then we redirect STDOUT into our current pipes write entry and then close the two pipes entry.

```
void    forking(t_data *data, int pipes[2], int i)
{
    t_cmd   **cmds;

    cmds = data -> cmd_data;
    if (i == 0)
        start(data -> cmd_data[0], pipes);
    else if (i == data -> num_cmds - 1)
        end(cmds[i], pipes, data -> prev_pipes);
    else
    {
        //check if there is prev_pipes
        if (data -> prev_pipes != -1)
        {
           //take input from prev_pipe
            if (dup2(data -> prev_pipes, STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
                print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", data, 1);
           //close pipes
            if (close(data -> prev_pipes) < 0)
                print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", data, 1);
        }
       //redirect outpur to pipes[1]
        if (dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
            print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", data, 1);
       //close both pipes entry for current process
        if (close(pipes[1]) < 0 || close(pipes[0]) < 0)
            print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", data, 1);
        run_cmd(cmds[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the end function where I output the result in the outfile and close the previous pipes and the current one

```
void    end(t_cmd *cmd, int pipes[2], int prev_pipes)
{
    char    *file;
    int     fd;

    file = cmd -> info -> files[1]-> file;
    fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    cmd -> info -> files[1]-> fd = fd;
    if (access(file, W_OK) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (fd < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (dup2(prev_pipes, STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (close(pipes[0]) < 0 || close(pipes[1]) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (close(fd) < 0 || close(prev_pipes) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    run_cmd(cmd);
}
```

This is the start process where I take input from the infile instead of the STDIN

```
void    start(t_cmd *cmd, int pipes[2])
{
    char    *file;
    int     fd;

    file = cmd -> info -> files[0]-> file;
    if (access(file, F_OK | R_OK) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    cmd -> info -> files[0]-> fd = fd;
    if (fd < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (close(fd) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    if (close(pipes[1]) < 0 || close(pipes[0]))
        print_err_and_exit("Pipex ", cmd -> info, 1);
    run_cmd(cmd);
}
```

Here is the function that is started each time an error is encountered
info -> pipes refered to the pipes that is used in the process

```
void    print_err_and_exit(char *str, t_data *info, int type)
{
    if (type)
        perror(str);
    else
        ft_putstr_fd(str, 2);
    if (info -> init_pipes)
        if (close(info -> pipes[0]) || close(info -> pipes[1]))
            perror("Error");
    free_all(info, EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

As I said My programs works perfectly when all commands does exist in shell but when I enter a bad command my program still works fine but I get in addition to the error message telling me that the command does not exit, another message is print to the screen telling "Bad file descriptor"
Command that would make an error occur :
./pipex infile cat catd ls wc outfile will get the following output
" Pipex : No such file or directory \n Pipex : Bad file descriptor"
The above command would refer to <infile cat | catd | ls | ws > outfile in shell.

Comment: What you describe sounds plausible.  Presumably the child downstream from the one handling the bad command produces that message as a result of its standard input being connected to a pipe with no writers.  Did you have a question about it?

Comment: I found the errors, it was in the error handling function where I close the pipes if any errors occurs. I am trying to really understand the pipes and yes I do have question about it. As my programs is here is there any improvement i can make about it ?

Comment: "Is there any improvement I can make?" is much too broad a question for SO, but if the program works correctly then such questions are well suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Once you have the code working correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".